# html document opens without CSS (Tailwind-CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I recently started working with Tailwind-CSS as my framework, and I finished my first practice project using it. However, when I try to open the .html file (index.html for example) in my browser, it loads the HTML file without loading the CSS. Why does that happen?

How can I deliver a project in Tailwind-CSS to a client if the CSS does not load?

Here is the index.html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet" type=".text/css"/>
    <title>Manage Landing Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
```

It may be worth noting that I have 3 projects done with Tailwind-CSS using VS Code. None of my three projects load any CSS when opened in browser, despite two being done by following tutorials on Tailwind-CSS on YT. They only load CSS when I open them through the Live Server extension for VS Code.

Comment: Remove .test/css

Comment: Typo: Standard MIME types don't start with a `.`. Browsers don't load CSS when the expected MIME type isn't one they recognise.

Comment: So I deleted the "type=".text/css", I also tried deleting just the "." prefix to text/css and neither worked. It still loads just pure HTML.

Comment: Then there's probably something wrong with the path, the URI to the file.

Comment: Since I started using Tailwind-CSS, I tried to keep working and built a simple website as a sample for my freelance work. This one does not load CSS either when I open the html document by right clicking then selecting open in browser option.

Comment: I mean that there's probably something wrong with `<link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">`. Open the html file in the browser, press F12 and then click the tab Console. Any mention of the css file being missing (404)?

Comment: I've done as you instructed and it showed an error message saying "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" for my output.css file which contains all the CSS of the page done with Tailwind.css